# XPath Axes: How to select text between <br/> nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, axes

Have such XML:

```
<td>
  text1
  <br/>
  text2
  <br/>
  text3
  <br/>
  text4
  <br/>
</td>
```

Want to select `text1 text2 text3 text4` **with spaces or CRLF between them**.
If I select `string(/td)` it selects `text1text2text3text4`. If I select `string(/td/text())` it selects only `text1`.
How to select all text but with spaces in-between?

Comment: Well the string value of the `td` element node should be all text including white space, I don't see how you would get solely the letters `text1text2text3text4` without any white space with `string(td)`. Can you tell us more details about the XPath engine that you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select `string(node-set)`, because `string()` will convert the *first node* from its argument to string only.

Hence you get `'\n text1'` from `string(td/text())`.

Just use `td/text()` and you will get five (!) not four text nodes.

Comment: Hint: Use `td/text()[normalize-space()]` to get rid of whitespace-only nodes. (`normalize-space()` collapses whitespace-only to the empty string, and the empty string is `false` in boolean context)

Comment: Thank you. Will do that way.